# Spring Boot : How to httpSession.invalidate() after return statement?

Tags: spring-boot, servlets, httpsession, try-finally

I am working on internationalization in `Spring boot`. Is it possible to `httpSession.invalidate()` after returning a page.

As an example

```
        try {
            return "finalPage";
        }finally {
            httpSession.invalidate();
        }
```

What I am trying to do is to show `finalPage.html` with selected language option first, after clear the session.

But this example first clears the session and then shows the `finalPage.html` in English not selected Italian. Which means if I choose Italian language for the `firstPage.html` I expect `finalPage.html` also in Italian language not default English.

Is it possible the above code example work the way as I wish?

**Note:** I have achieved my wish by using `Thymeleaf` tags, I want to do this on the java side if possible.

Comment: Can't you create a separate API which only invalidates the session and call it as required ?

Comment: Thank you Utsav10, I thought I could solve it without creating another endpoint. I think I'll keep the `Thymeleaf` solution.